# Indent Break Lines in Div With :before

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a `:before` element and some lines separated with `<br/>`.

The code is like this

```
<div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

the CSS is like this

```
.foo:before {
    content: "X";
    display: "inline-block";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

You can access the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/g5929/

As you can see the element will be displayed like this

```
X Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Is there any way to display the second and next lines to have indentation like the first line?

It would be something like this.

```
X Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/g5929/1/ ?

Comment: according to css3 spec, its `::before`, `:before` is old syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g5929/2/

```css
.foo {
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.foo:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "X";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

You can use `padding-left` and then absolutely position the `.foo:before`.

Comment: what if he wants the `X` larger by changing the font-size of `:before`? you should use `em` instead of `px` here. Even using `em`, looks like it's hard to set the `padding-left` of the `div` accordingly.

Comment: i would avoid using `em`. `px` is definitive. He would have to adjust the padding to fit the `X`.

Comment: I'm actually planning to use it using image instead of plain text like "X", so `px` is more preferable. :)

Comment: @chovy I would like give you this example to show how ***dynamic/flexible*** is so attractive http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/sNU8a/1/ You can just change the font-size of `:before` to what you want. BTW, `em` always has its own advantage, even in this case you can use `em` to make it more dynamic.

Comment: Note that `inline-block` is a keyword and should not be quoted. (I've edited out the quotes from the code)

Answer (score 4):

You should do like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
    margin-left:20px;
    position: relative;

}
.foo:before {
    content: "X";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position:absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sNU8a/)**

Comment: this is also not really dynamic, see my comment under chovy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve the effect using below code in this case you no need to add `<br>` tag.

check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tuforave/1/edit)**.

```
.foo:before {
    content: "X";
    display: "inline-block";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0;

}
.foo{white-space:pre-wrap;position:relative;}
```

**HTML Code is here.**

```
<div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```